# I dont see image thumbnails in my ubuntu 16.04 since I reckoon I installed UbuntuTweak

Tags: 16.04, thumbnails

[image]

I tried hard solving this problem having some research on the net and trying with some coding.

I tried already erasing the thumbnails cache and didnt work

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.thumbnails/* ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
```

Answer (score 0):

**To set view thumbnails to always :**

Open a terminal :

```
dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/show-image-thumbnails '"always"'
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried that before, no luck though.